# JQuery AJAX fails with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function for doing ajax calls (line numbers supplied):

```
9 function doAjax(url, args){
10    var retVal;
11    retVal =   $.ajax({  
12                    type: "GET",
13                    url: url,
14                    data: args,
15                    async: false,
16                }).responseText;
17    if(retVal==null || retVal=="")retval=99;
18    return retVal;
19 }
```

When I use IE8, I get an error stating:

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB7.1; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDR; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Mon, 25 Jul 2011 17:45:36 UTC

Message: Expected identifier, string or number

Line: 17

Char: 21

Code: 0

URI: local host web server

This script works perfectly fine with FireFox. Being a novice, I am at a loss as to why this is generating an error. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does anyone else laugh to themselves a little when they hear AJAX refer to a function which is not asynchronous, and does not use xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try taking out the comma after

```
async: false
```

Putting a comma after the last member of an object can cause IE to freak out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. That did indeed resolve my issue. Many times in life it is the very smallest of things that cause the most problems.